# JLabel doesn't show up until you maximize my frame

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, maximize

I was looking for this situation, but apparently there is no other question about this, so, here I go.

I'm making a school project which requires that I make a JFrame and even though I had a horrible time with ActionEvents, I finally could make it work, so after I got some info in my JFrame which I need that shows in a JLabel an answer and, well, it does, the only thing is that nothing happens after I click my button, but it happens when I maximize or resize the window itself.

```
    button1= new JButton("Add user");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           user= input1.getText();
        if(user.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have an error there!");
        }
        else {
        output2 = new JLabel("thx for registering, "+user);
        output2.setBounds(10,40,150,20);
        panel.add(output2);
        }
    }
    });
    button1.setBounds(310,10,140,20);
    panel.add(button1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers, so let the layout manger determine the size/location of a component. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples to get you started.

When you add a component to a visible GUI the basic code should be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The revalidate() will invoke the layout manger to give the component a size/location. The repaint() makes sure all the components get painted.

Comment: Well, I tried to work without the .setBounds() and adding what you gave me, .revalidate() didn't work, so I tried with validate() + repaint(), but it didn't work, so I reSet all the setBounds() plus the validate() and repaint() and it work correctly, thanks alot.

Comment: Why do you ask a question when you don't listen to the suggestions? If you use a layout manager it will work!!! Also, the method is revalidate() not validate(). The revalidate() is for Swing and validate() for AWT. Yes it may work most of the time, but again learn to use Swing the way it was designed to be used. With your current hack it may work for a simply program but once programs get more complex you need to understand how Swing works so you don't have design problems.

Comment: I gave you the answer and then 13 minutes later you said it didn't work. That is NOT enough time to read the tutorial, download the working code, understand how the code works and then restructure your existing code. So my point was you took a short cut and did not take the time to learn to use Swing effectively which will cause you problems in the future. You can spend the time to learn Swing now, or unlearn it later which will take more time.