# When I run my code in Eclipse, my JLabel's disappear until I resize the window

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

So when I run this code:

```
public class Game
{
    // DECLARING Java objects to later use
    JFrame window;
    Container con;
    JPanel titleNamePanel, startButtonPanel, signaturePanel;
    JLabel titleNameLabel, signatureLabel;
    Font titleFont = new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.BOLD, 80);
    Font signature = new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 15);
    Font normalFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 30);
    JButton startButton;
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // calling constructor
        new Game();
    }

    public Game() {
        // GAME WINDOW creation
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(800,600);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        con = window.getContentPane();
        
        // TITLE NAME PANEL for title text
        titleNamePanel = new JPanel();
        titleNamePanel.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 150);
        titleNamePanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        titleNameLabel = new JLabel("GAME");
        titleNameLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        titleNameLabel.setFont(titleFont);
        
        // START BUTTON PANEL for button housing
        startButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        startButtonPanel.setBounds(300, 400, 200, 100);
        startButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        
        // START BUTTON customization
        startButton = new JButton("START");
        startButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        startButton.setForeground(Color.white);
        startButton.setFont(normalFont);
        
        // SIGNATURE PANEL for text and customization
        signaturePanel = new JPanel();
        signaturePanel.setBounds(640, 525, 150, 40);
        signaturePanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        signatureLabel = new JLabel("coded by connor");
        signatureLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        signatureLabel.setFont(signature);
        
        // ADDING both labels to panels and retrieving content pane information
        titleNamePanel.add(titleNameLabel);
        signaturePanel.add(signatureLabel);
        startButtonPanel.add(startButton);
        con.add(titleNamePanel);
        con.add(startButtonPanel);
        con.add(signaturePanel);
    }
}`
```

My code works but my window just displays black until I maximize the window and then return it back to normal like this: [black window with JLabels gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcCp7.png)-----------------[JLabels back when I maximize the screen and then minimize it back to it's original dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQBQn.png)

I'm just wondering if anyone knows a fix for this that I'm overlooking. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491783/jlabel-doesnt-show-up-until-you-maximize-my-frame

Comment: `setLayout(null)` this is the problem. Use layouts. If you recode the app. using layouts, get back to us.